# Show Blog posts from other site to WordPress without RSS Feed

Tags: posts

I have developed a WordPress theme for my Client for his Website. From a long time My client is operating his Blog on ThreeVillagePatch. He is an active member on this site and frequently adds new posts to this Site. Now that I have made new theme for his site, he wants me to show Blog posts from ThreeVillagePath.com to his own website North Shore injury Lawyer. Here, I am providing links for both, Please help me as to how can i fulfill this and show Blog posts posted on [ThreeVillagePath.com](http://threevillage.patch.com/users/mark-t-freeley-esq/blog_posts/) to [northshoreinjurylawyer](http://northshoreinjurylawyer.com/blog/)

Please Note: It would be ideal if i can show both excerpt and Full blog post content as well.

Thank you in advance
Chetan

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/allowing-a-user-to-write-a-post-from-another-website) question.

Essentially, you can use the [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) protocol to submit posts to both the blogs at the same time.